# How can I restore the changes to shell variable?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

For the purpose of an experiment...

Suppose I did this

```
bash="unset DISPLAY; export DISPLAY"
```

so I can make `DISPLAY` undefined. How can I restore the original value set? Or at least know what it was?

Answer (score 5):

In general you write it down before hand.

If you're asking about this in theory, then you simply store the old value somewhere else before modifying it, then put it back whenever you want.

If you're asking about this because now you're screwed and are hoping that there's something that will bail you out, then I have bad news for you...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this (like `cd -` to move back and forth between most recent `cd` commands for instance)

What is the context of doing this .. do you want this to be available automatically? I am not aware of this as a feature of any shell.

One obvious solution would be to explicitly save the variable before you change it, and then later restore it. Using the VENDOR environment variable as an example:

```
$ echo $VENDOR
intel
```

Save the original value:

```
$ pre_VENDOR=$VENDOR
$ echo $pre_VENDOR
intel
```

Assign a new value:

```
$ VENDOR='Zippy'
$ echo $VENDOR
Zippy
```

Restore the original value:

```
$ VENDOR=$pre_VENDOR
$ echo $VENDOR
intel
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there's no undo. Save the value in another variable (or in a file or wherever you like) if you want to have it available later.

```
old_DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
unset DISPLAY
…
DISPLAY=$old_DISPLAY
```

If you want to run a single command without the environment variable, use `env`.

```
env -u DISPLAY emacs
```

You can also use the syntax `VAR=VALUE COMMAND` to set the environment variable `VAR` to the specified value only for this one command.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
$ DISPLAY=:1 xterm & # shows the xterm window on display :1
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

You can't unset a variable this way, but you can set it to an empty value, which is often good enough.

You can also keep changes local to a subshell. Parentheses delimit commands to perform in a subshell.

```
$ env | grep -E 'FOO|BAR'
FOO=value_of_FOO
BAR=value_of_BAR
$ (export FOO=other_value; unset BAR; env | grep -E 'FOO|BAR')
FOO=other_value
$ env | grep -E 'FOO|BAR'
FOO=value_of_FOO
BAR=value_of_BAR
```

You can run a separate shell with a different environment. Type `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to the parent shell.

```
$ bash
$ # change the environment, change directories, etc.
$ exit
$ # now you're back to the parent shell with its environment as you left it
```